# A few rebus puzzles

Tags: rebus

First attempt at rebus puzzles, hope you'll enjoy them:

**1)**

[image: 1]

**2)**

[image: 2]

**3)**

[image: 3]

Comment: So far, so good :)   Take the [tour](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and have fun!

Comment: well this is a good puzzle for a first time!

Comment: I wonder if there's anywhere in the world that has chequer cabs?

Comment: @Strawberry I googled it and it seems there was [at least one](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checker_Motors_Corporation) manufacturer.

Comment: Filing for bankruptcy in 2009 rather emphasises the 'was' part of that sentence ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Community Wiki crediting each solver:

1.

> MOONLIGHT - Solved by @AmruthA - Moo 'n' light. A cow goes moo and the bulb gives off light.

2.

> CABINET - Solved by @BeastlyGerbil - It's a cab (taxi) in the letters ET, giving cab in et

3.

> BORDER CONTROL - Solved by @pb8330 - It's the abbreviation for control next to a line which represents a border.

Comment: Line of control is better answer i feel

Answer (score 12):

Guessing 1 -

> it is *moonlight* because cow makes sound moo- and new line 'n'(\n)and then light from bulb.As bulb is in below line of cow.

2 might also be -

> EXIT - ta**XI** is covering the letter "XI" and it is moving out.

3 might be -

> Line of control .

Comment: Good guess, you are close.

Comment: I've already solved 2

Comment: Yep, you got them all. Congratulations !

Comment: @Ria he has 2 wrong though

Comment: Moo 'n' light ?

Comment: is 1) correct ? i simply guessed..@Ria what about 'n'

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil 2 correct ..

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Sorry, you are right, I didn't notice. In this case which answer should I accept?

Comment: @Ria For full clarity, I suggest leaving a comment on each answer to say exactly which ones are right (I almost downvoted your question because I thought EXIT was the intended answer for #2, but CABINET is much better). Then accept [whichever you like](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1732/5373) :-)

Comment: @Ria I can also create a communtiy wiki which credits each solver, and no one gets the accept then (but you can accept the answer still). I've added the answer

Answer (score 10):

I think the third one is

> [border control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_control).

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: I go with the cabinet.

Answer (score 7):

1 is

> Moonlight as found by Amruth

2 is

> CABINET - it is a cab in et

3 might be

> Out of control. Or a more likely suggestion from @pb8330 - border control

Comment: Correct, keep going!